# How can I select and display a random data from multiple rows and columns in a spreadsheet in LibreOffice Calc?

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc, libreoffice-basic

I've a spreadsheet in LibreOffice Calc as shown below in the figure. I want to select  and display a random data from multiple rows and columns in that spreadsheet.

[image]

Comment: What have you already tried? Was it a formula using [**RANDBETWEEN()**](https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/en-US/text/scalc/01/04060106.html?DbPAR=CALC#bm_id3164669) and [**OFFSET()**](https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/en-US/text/scalc/01/04060109.html?DbPAR=CALC#bm_id3158430) or [**INDEX()**](https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/en-US/text/scalc/01/04060109.html?DbPAR=CALC#bm_id3151221)? Pretty much any of the combination will give you the desired result: `=INDEX($A$1:$F$10;RANDBETWEEN(1;ROWS(A1:F10));RANDBETWEEN(1;COLUMNS(A1:F10)))` or `=OFFSET($A$1;RANDBETWEEN(0;9);RANDBETWEEN(0;5))`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works. Then come back and [edit] your question, adding details: How would you like to select that random data? Where do you want to display it? You might like to provide a [mre] that uses a dummy formula at the place where you want the random data obtained.